# C#, How to make function that order list as we need in parameter

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

```
public static List<someclass> OrderAsc(
    List<someclass> object, 
    specific_field_by_someone )
{
    return object.OrderBy(...get field to be sorted...);
}
```

I just want to make data structure like this

```
Dictionary<string, ???> data_table = new Dictionary<string, ????>() {
    {"id", x => x.id },
    {"name", x => x.name }
}
```

that can be used with

```
object.OrderBy(data_table["name"])...
```

Comment: I'm really confused here you want to order a dictionary? you want to order a list? do you want a list to dictionary?

Comment: what does ??? and ???? represent?

Comment: This should be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: I'm sorry to make you guys confuse..
I just want to know how to make delegate to method OrderBy and OrderByDescending..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
public static List<someclass> OrderAsc(
    List<someclass> object, 
    specific_field_by_someone )
{
    var data_table = new Dictionary<string, Func<someclass,object>>() 
    {
        {"id", x => x.id },
        {"name", x => x.name }
    }

    return object.OrderBy(data_dable["name"]);
}
```